# Can purpose be described through a "how-clause"?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

> The main purpose of this period of the year, when the company
> intensifies training for its employees, is (***how***) to acquire better performance at every level.

My question is: Would the use of ***how*** make this sentence incorrect? I find this structure in other languages (with "how"), but when I translate into English, I hesitate to put "how" in for some reason. If it is incorrect, could someone explain why?

The question is not limited to this particular example which may not be the best.

Comment: No. *The main purpose ... is **to learn how** to acquire [blah blah]*. Or *...is to **teach** [workers] how to [do stuff]*.

Comment: Would "The main purpose ... is to acquire" be wrong?

Comment: The basic construction is *the purpose is **to do something***, where the highlighted element can be any ***infinitve-based clause*** that makes sense as a "purpose" (something you want ***to do*** or ***to achieve***).

Comment: "How" is not required. Without it, the infinitival clause is predicative complement of "be", where it’s intended as a subtype of ascriptive Predicative Complement: it ascribes a purpose to the predicand (the subject). If you include "how", the clause becomes an interrogative (embdded question), but that would make no sense here.

Answer (score 1):

The simplified form of your sentence is as follows:

> The purpose is how to acquire X

This means "the purpose" is the *way* or *method* to acquire X.  A purpose is normally a reason and not a method of doing something, so this sounds strange.

> The purpose is to acquire X

This is answering the question "what is the purpose?" - so here we are directly defining the purpose.